# get filedialouge into tk.text

Tags: python, tkinter

im trying to get text from a loaded file into a ktinker .text, here is the code i have so far, i dont quite understand where a file goes once you have opened it with filedialouge

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter as tk

interface = tk.Tk()
interface.geometry("500x500")
interface.title("Text display")

def openfile():
    return filedialog.askopenfilename()

button = ttk.Button(interface, text="Open text File", command=openfile)  # <------
button.grid(column=1, row=1)

T = tk.Text(interface, height=2, width=30)

T.insert(tk.END, "text file contents here")
T.grid(column=1, row=2)

interface.mainloop()
```

Comment: `askopenfilename` gives you file name which you have to `open()` and `read()` and put text to `Text`. Function executed by button sends `return` to nowhere and you have to do it all inside `openfile()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's up to you to do something with the return value of `askopenfilename`. Returning it from a button callback is pointless because nothing will see the returned value.

For example, you could save it as a global variable used by some other part of your program:

```
def openfile():
    global current_file
    current_file = filedialog.askopenfilename()
```

Another thing you might do is actually open the file and insert the contents into your text widget:

```
def openfile():
    global current_file
    current_file = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    if current_file:
        with open(current_file, "r") as f:
            data = f.read()
            T.insert("end", data)
```

Though, if you're going to immediately open the file you might want to consider using `askopenfile` rather than `askopenfilename`. The former opens the file and returns a handle, the later simply returns the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Button can't get value returned from function. You may have to do all inside `openfile` - open file, read it and put text in `Text`

```
# from tkinter import * # not preferred
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog

# --- functions ---

def openfile():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    if filename:
        data = open(filename).read()
        text.delete('1.0', 'end') # see Bryan Oakley comment why it is better to use string instead of float (but in this situation float 1.0 would work as expected)
        text.insert('end', data)

# --- main ---

interface = tk.Tk()
interface.geometry("500x500")
interface.title("Text display")

button = ttk.Button(interface, text="Open text File", command=openfile)
button.grid(column=1, row=1)

text = tk.Text(interface, height=2, width=30)
text.grid(column=1, row=2)

text.insert('end', "text file contents here")

interface.mainloop()
```

Comment: text indexes are strings, not floating point numbers. A floating point will work, but only for certain values (eg: the floating point `1.10` and the string `"1.10"` represent two different characters)

Comment: @BryanOakley I added in code infomation about your comment.